# VBA for searching string in different Excel sheet in sheets column contain sentence and display the sheets contain that string

Tags: vba, excel

Ex: I want to search " return order" string  in all sheets but column in sheets contain sentence in it ex(  return order is not reached ) .any sheet contain required string then that sheet should be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub ertdfgcvb()
Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, str1 As String
str1 = " return order"
On Error Resume Next
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Index > ActiveSheet.Index Then 'after the currently open worksheet
        Set rng = ws.Cells.Find(What:=str1, LookAt:=xlPart) 'tries to find your string
        ws.Select 'if it manages then selects the worksheet
        rng.Select 'and the cell in which it found the string
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Your specifications weren't quite clear, here's a script you can start out with.
No, follow-up is out of the question, we're not on-call programming service.